# How do I remove the first two words in string which aren't separated by a space?

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"Product DescriptionThe Signature Series treatment makes the strategy
guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN
WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus
objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the
official guide, show locations of units,..."
```

I though of doing this to remove `Product Description`:

```
description_hash[:description] = @data.at_css('.featureReview span').text[/.*\.\.\./m].delete("Product Description")
```

But I got this:

```
"ThSgaSammakhagygaCOLLECTIBLEITEMfSaCafIIfa.Sgl-layCAMAIGNWALKTHROUGHvallblmbah,lgbbjvhghhamag.ExlvMASflyhffalg,hwlaf,..."
```

I think I just told Ruby to remove all the letters in the words `Product Description` (plus spaces). But I just want to remove the first two words instead.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: -1 For writing `description_hash[:description] = @data.at_css('.featureReview span').text` without any explanation. It is not clear at all what that is. Perhaps, that part is not related to the question, and hence should not have been written in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = "Product DescriptionThe Signature Series treatment makes the strategy guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the official guide, show locations of units,..."
text[/.*\.\.\./m].sub(/\AProduct Description/, '')
# => "The Signature Series treatment makes the strategy guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the official guide, show locations of units,..."
```

Comment: Why not just `text.gsub("Product Description", "")` ?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, not to accidently remove `Product Description` in the middle.

Comment: @falsetru, Amit Kumar Gupta, Why are you suggesting `gsub`? Isn't `sub` more appropriate? And falsetru, for this purpose, it is better to use `\A` than `^`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `String#sub` method.

```
2.0.0-p247 :011 > foo.sub("Product Description", "")
```

which I think might also replace any consecutive occurences of "Product Description"

EDIT: falsetru's answer is technically superior, OP. You should try that out.

Answer (score 1):

A really clean way to do this is:

```
str = "Product DescriptionThe Signature Series treatment makes the strategy guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the official guide, show locations of units,..."

str[/\AProduct Description(.+)/, 1] # => "The Signature Series treatment makes the strategy guide a COLLECTIBLE ITEM for StarCraft II fans. Single-player CAMPAIGN WALKTHROUGH covers all possible mission branches, including bonus objectives throughout the campaign. Exclusive MAPS found only in the official guide, show locations of units,..."
```

While you *can* strip the first "offending" text using a search-and-replace, since you know what you want to ignore, and you want the rest, you can easily skip it and tell Ruby to return just the desired text. So, grab just what you want and forget about deleting the unwanted text.

String's [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method is really useful for this. Among other things, it lets us pass a regex with a capture-group, and then return only that captured text:

```
str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil
```